# Question regarding norm of hessian of function

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,\langle,\rangle)$ be a Riemannian manifold and $f$ be a smooth function in $M$. Please give me an explanation how we get the following statement
$$(\nabla_i\nabla_jf)(\nabla^i\nabla^jf)=2\langle \nabla\nabla f,\nabla\nabla f\rangle,$$
where $\nabla^i=g^{ij}\nabla_j$.

Comment: Is $\nabla \nabla f$ supposed to be $\nabla \boldsymbol{\cdot}\nabla f$? As written the expression makes no sense.

Comment: Why is there a $2$ on the right side?

Comment: @K.defaoite: Yes. it is $\nabla \cdot\nabla f$.

Comment: @Yuval: That is what I am asking. I don't know why there is 2.